# Retrieving Date function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table with the hire_date column.
I am stuck with one query related to the date function, where I have used data type 'DATE'  to insert date of hiring and using DATE_FORMAT fun. to retrieve no. of employees hired in every month, but in SQL-server it is not supporting the date_format function.
I'm using SQL -server

Query: - list of the no.of employee hired every month in ascending order.

```
select date_format(hire_date,'%b') month, count(*)
from employee
group by DATE_FORMAT(hire_date,'%b')
order by month
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: no `date_format`  in SQL Server, use `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0):

`date_format(hire_date,'%b')` in MySQL will return abbreviated monthname. However, you can still have this functionality by combining  `MONTHNAME` with `LEFT` in SQL Server.

```
select LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,hire_date),3) month, count(*)
from employee
group by LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,hire_date),3)
order by month
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can directly use:

```
select MONTH(hire_date), count(*)
from employee
group by MONTH(hire_date)
order by MONTH(hire_date)
```

or

```
select hire_date.MONTH, count(*)
from employee
group by hire_date.MONTH
order by hire_date.MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Month(Hire_Date),count('x') 'count' from employee
group by Month(Hire_Date)
order by Month(Hire_Date) asc
```